# [JSoup]How do I access a value inside of a tag

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

Im stuck parsing out the value "datetime" here:

```
<div class="job_date_added" itemprop="datePosted"><time datetime="2014-07-16">16.07.14</time></div>
```

What I am doing right now is:

```
 Elements dateElement = element.select(".job_date_added [datetime]");
 String timeAdded = dateElement.text();
```

Which returns: 16.07.14 (the german date format). When I want to write this to my DB it automatically screws up the Dates. So I want to access the value INSIDE  - specifically "2014-07-16".

I tried to google this, but I'm having a hard time finding information, since I don't know how to call this part.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get attribute of found element then use `attr` method, not `text`.

This should do what you want

```
String timeAdded = dateElement.attr("datetime");
```